# Finding the length/area of the object using 2d web cam

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have to calculate the **area, or length** of the objects present in the frame.

As i use the **2d** camera, the distance from the camera can't be found.

In this case, i am planning to draw a **constant(X CM) line** in the back ground where its length is known in CM/M.

Please find the **attachment** for a sample input image. (Yellow Line is a Constant line)

[image]

Consider that a person or an object stands in front of a wall, where the constant **line is drawn**.

Is there any way to calculate the distance of other objects with reference to the constant line?

Comment: I will be difficult to do so, as we have no idea on how far each object is from the camera. If all the objects were at the same distance, it would have been possible

Comment: well, you will know the length of the known line, but the size of any object that has a different distance tot he camera than that line is still ambiguous. Just imagine a ball that's "flying" in the air, once far away from the camera and once close to the camera. Without any distance information you can't do much there, I guess.

Comment: did you try to use the contours?  if not use should and than use  cv::approxPolyDP function to know which object you working with and the moments function could help you to get the center of you shap so you can calculat the distance!

Comment: If the camera is very far (say 10 meters or more) you can approximate the distance as infinite (very roughly) and thus you can extract some information from those objects which are close to the wall.

Answer (score 0):

First, it isn't a line.  It is a parcel.  A line is non-physical.  The parcel of pixels has both area and length.  The natural unit of measurement of images is pixels.  Units of length are both non-physical and require assumptions.

Second, you can do a thresholded 2-d convolution.  [PIV-sleuth](http://ltcf.tam.uiuc.edu/downloads.html) uses 2d convolution.  It can allow some faster, more accurate measurement in images.  Peak intensity will tell you something about the length or area.  You can also use row-sum and column sum very quickly to get ideas of lengths.  It helps if the images are aligned to the pixel-axes in your image. Use of affine transformations can help you test various rotations for suitability.